# Conditional one-to-one pairing

Tags: sas, analytics, data-analysis

I have tried to find similar examples or concepts to this and have not had much luck. Even if you can't help with a specific solution to my problem, I could use any help going in the right direction.

I am trying to match pairs of transactions conditionally on the days between the transactions (there is further underlying association not important for the example). There should be a one-to-one relationship between a transaction from the old account to the new account, best determined by the lowest # of days between transactions.

In the example below, transactions 1-4 in the data from an old account are associated with transactions 5-6 from a new account. I want to define a one-to-one relationship between transactions 1 (old) and 5 (new) because it has the fewest days difference, which would exclude both transactions 1 and 5 from further pairing consideration.

There is a best-match tie between transactions 2 or 4 (old) and 6 (new) which both have 60 days difference. Transaction pair 2-6 would be selected because it appears first.

| Old Account | New Account | Days Between Transactions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 5 |
| 1 | 6 | 15 |
| 2 | 5 | 50 |
| 2 | 6 | 60 |
| 3 | 5 | 100 |
| 3 | 6 | 70 |
| 4 | 5 | 200 |
| 4 | 6 | 60 |

Want:

| Old Account | New Account | Days Between Transactions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 | 60 |

Thanks!

Comment: Does that output actually align with your input? That's exactly what you want based on the input data? I fixed your formatting issues but you deleted the output. Please repost it to make your question understandable.

Comment: The 2nd table shows up correctly in the preview but is unformatted after the edit is saved. Depending on the logic, I suppose that the output/2nd table would be only two rows (transaction 1 and 5, transaction 2 and 6) as it would have defined only the one-to-one matches after deduping.

Comment: Fixed it again for you, so your output is exactly as expected based on the input data?

Comment: After thinking about it more, the output would likely be expected to contain only 2 rows - the first two transaction pairs observed with the fewest days between transactions. In case of duplication (2-6 and 4-6 with the same days) the first observation would be the matched pair, which would allow transaction 4 a chance to match elsewhere.

Comment: I think this is a tree search problem, searching for shortest unique path. I can't answer this unfortunately but if you post on communities.sas.com there will be a few individuals who can answer it.